# Getting Windows UAC Level Windows 8/8.1 on Win32 C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-8.1, uac

i am making OpenCL Service that cannot be made regular service for Windows 8 and 8.1.
So i need to launch as an Application.

My App needs to wake another application as an administrative or not , depends on the situation.
But i cannot get UAC Level on Windows 8/8.1

i tried this code:

```
    BOOL IsUacEnabled() {
        return checkSecurityKey(_T("EnableLUA"));
    }


    BOOL checkSecurityKey( TCHAR *lpchKey )
    {
        LPCTSTR pszSubKey = _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System");
        LPCTSTR pszValue = lpchKey;
        DWORD dwType = 0;
        DWORD dwValue = 0;
        DWORD dwValueSize = sizeof( DWORD );
        //KEY_QUERY_VALUE
        if ( ERROR_SUCCESS != SHGetValue( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pszSubKey, lpchKey, 
            &dwType, &dwValue, &dwValueSize) )
        {
                return FALSE;
        }

        return dwValue != 0;
    }
```

But although i disable uac level to 0 , i got always TRUE from return of IsUacEnabled function.
Does somebody know how to get system uac level ?

Comment: There is no need to query anyone... just execute the app as admin, then UAC will be shown (if eanbled) or not... why do you bother???

Comment: You shouldn't need to know what the current UAC policy is.  Can you better explain what you're actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's a linker setting.

You need to set the "UAC Execution Level" to "requireAdministrator" in "Linker/Manifest File". You can view a hardcopy from VisualStudio here:

[Hardcopy: requireAdministrator settings in Visual Studio](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3ku1ache5m0lh8/requireAdministrator.PNG)

Then at application start, the program will be run with administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

This code gets the current elevation level of the calling app:

```
if (IsWindowsVistaOrGreater())
{   HANDLE hToken;
    BOOL bOK = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_READ, &hToken);
    DWORD infoLen;
    bOK = GetTokenInformation(hToken, 
        TokenElevationType,     // type of info to retrieve
        &elevationType,         // receives return value
        sizeof(elevationType), 
        &infoLen);              // receives returned length
}
```

Comment: Similar source: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppUACSelfElevation-5bfc52dd